# Y86 program stops midway through throwing exception "Invalid instruction f4"

Tags: assembly, y86, illegal-instruction

What does this mean? I can find next to nothing about this online, best I could try was figuring out what "f4" meant but even that makes zero sense to me. Could somebody please explain this to me?

What does "Invalid instruction f4" mean in the context of Y86 Assembly?

It stops at

```
popl %ebp
ret
```

it reaches ret, then the program ends prematurely

Comment: Means you messed up the stack in code not shown and so `ret` jumps to some garbage location which happens to contain a byte `f4`.

Comment: What is the offending instruction's address?